# Read and Sort 2 million items in Java at a time

Tags: java, memory-management, collections, out-of-memory

Today I have an interview, interviewer asked me this question. He gave me a method asked me what object modelling you would do 
to call this method with 2 million records. Assume JVM can hold 25k items at a time. Assume we are reading data from database.

```
public void sort(List<Object> input){

    //sort the list and write sorted data to file.
}
```

I know we need to read data in chunks and process, But how to merge the result at the end?

Comment: [Map reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)?

Comment: This is maybe not what the interviewer had in mind, but I would let the database do the sorting.

Comment: Looks like the interviewer was looking for magic work, "Map Reduce". You can also use a modified version of Merge Sort to get the results. Basically you implement a combine step, where you read one item at a time from the files and write them in the sorted order.

Comment: since the jvm has no enough memory to hold all items and sort in memory, i thing offline merge sort is what you want.

Comment: You should read from the database in the required order via the `ORDER BY` SQL clause. Have the database do the work. That's what it's for.

Comment: divide and conquer, (Jup: MapReduce if you go hadoop)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm